# Excel VBA - If cell begins with "find" then return value of a different cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a lot of rows.  What I would like is to search every cell in column N.  If the cell starts with "find" (would like it to be case insensitive), then return the value in column A (same row).  Example.  If N2 begins with "Find" or "FIND" or "find" (or any other variation), then return A2.  The worksheet is "Master", and I'd like for this to run on a different worksheet.  My version of Excel is 2013.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show what you have already tried that isn't working?

Comment: How about just using an AutoFilter? Place a text filter on column N for "Begins with", setting the search string to "find". Then copy the result to the different sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the value in column A of all rows with starting with 'find' in any combination of cases.
**Edit**: Have updated so that it looks for values in column N of Sheet1 and pastes the column A results to Sheet2 column A.

```
Sub Find()

    Dim rFoundAddress As Range
    Dim sFirstAddress As String
    Dim x As Long

    x = 1
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(14)
        Set rFoundAddress = .Find("find*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAddress = rFoundAddress.Address
            Do
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(x, 1) = .Cells(rFoundAddress.Row, 1)
                x = x + 1
                Set rFoundAddress = .FindNext(rFoundAddress)
            Loop While Not rFoundAddress Is Nothing And _
                rFoundAddress.Address <> sFirstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

It will find a match with these:

- Findthis
- FIND this
- fInD this

but won't find a match with:

- aaFiND this

Comment: Thanks Darren!  Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The below will print the values in A to the immediate window.

```
Sub returnA()
    With Sheets("Master")
        For Each cell In .Range("N2:" & .Range("N2").End(xlDown).Address)
            If UCase(Left(cell.Value, 4)) = "FIND" Then
                Debug.Print .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```